# Sent a receipt through Facebook Messenger after user logged in with Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I'm trying to sent my customers a receipt through Facebook Messenger. They have already logged in to my website using Facebook oAuth2.

I can get their name, email, pictures, id and some other stuff. But in order to initiate a conversation it seems like I need their PSID - which you can only get after a user has messaged me first.

But I've seen other companies sent receipts through Messenger without the customer having to initate the conversation. How can I do this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

Comment: people must somehow approve a bot, you cannot send them messages just because they authorized your app (and not the bot). for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button